# Is there a core Perl module for SSL/TLS support?

Tags: perl, ssl, https

Does Perl support SSL/TLS via a core modules?

I am using `HTTP::Tiny` and want to fetch `https` url without installing any library and depending external libraries and XS.

Is there an option to let `HTTP::Tiny` to work with SSL without relying on OpenSSL, or is there any pure Perl module for fetching data with SSL out of the box without the need for XS modules?

Comment: Crypto libraries... not something that you want to re-implement in every language where they're needed.

Comment: I added the ssl tag so Steffen Ullrich will notice this question. He usually has a lot to say about this kind of thing.

Comment: @simbabque: I've noticed it but Sinan already had the perfect answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what is the best way to bundle  openssl and your module NET::SSLeay with perl app if i already know the OS ?

Comment: @smith: This is a different question your original one. Please don't ask new questions inside a comment.

Answer (score 11):

SSL/TLS support is provided by [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay) and [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL). Modules such as [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) and [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) interface with the [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) routines via those layers.

There is no core or pure Perl module supporting HTTPS.

Comment: [Here's proof](https://grep.metacpan.org/search?q=ssl&qd=Module%3A%3ACoreList&qft=&qci=on) that there has not been any module with `/ssl/i` in its name in the Perl core, at least since the `corelist` utility has been around.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can avoid using XS with Protocol::TLS module. It's pure perl and you can use it above core socket module.

Second, you can avoid using OpenSSL with Crypt::MatrixSSL. MatrixSSL seems lightweight and secure. See IO::Stream::MatrixSSL for example code.

Comment: number of published vulnerabilities is not an indicator of how secure a library is. If anything, a low amount of vulnerabilities is an indicator that nobody is testing it extensively